# TortoiseGit Commit window make none selected as default

Tags: tortoisegit

In the commit window of TortoiseGit , all files are selected by default. I would like to have "none" or no file selected by default.

Is there any setting to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to TortoiseGit settings -> Dialogs 2 and remove the check for "Select items automatically".

Comment: I actually went through those options , but missed it. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to TG 2.13, I had the opposite issue (no items selected by default, undesired behavior for me), even though [Select items automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dpr78.png) was checked.
Uncheck it, click "Apply". Check it back, click "Apply". It fixed it for me.

Full path to this option:
TG Settings → General → Dialogs2